# ANTLR v3 grammar for boolean/conditional expression

Tags: grammar, antlr3

I'm taking a first stab at creating a grammar for expressions like:

```
(foo = bar or (bar = "bar" and baz = 45.43)) and test = true
```

My grammar so far looks like:

```
grammar filter;

tokens {
    TRUE = 'true';
    FALSE = 'false';
    AND = 'and';
    OR = 'or';
    LT = '<';
    GT = '>';
    EQ = '=';
    NEQ = '!=';
    PATHSEP = '/';
    LBRACK = '[';
    RBRACK = ']';
    LPAREN = '(';
    RPAREN = ')';
}

expression : or_expression EOF;

or_expression : and_expression (OR or_expression)*;

and_expression : term (AND term)*;

term : atom ( operator atom)? | LPAREN expression RPAREN;

atom : ID | INT | FLOAT | STRING | TRUE | FALSE;

operator : LT | GT | EQ | NEQ;

INT : '0'..'9'+;
FLOAT : ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')*;
STRING : '"' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|' ')* '"';
ID : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
```

But in ANTLRWorks 1.4.3, I get the parse tree:

[image: The resulting parse tree with the above input]

But for the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong with my grammar. What token is it missing here?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify the `atom ( operator atom)?` alternative in the `atom` production, I should perhaps mention that atoms should be able to be free-standing without comparison to another atom. E.g. `a or b` is a valid expression.

Answer (score 5):

I'm answering to my own question here. I found two problems with my grammar. The first was easy to spot; I had put `EOF` at the end of my top-level rule:

```
expression : or_expression EOF;
```

The `EOF` was thus the missing token. My solution was remove the `EOF` from the `expression` rule, and instead introduce a rule above it:

```
filter: expression EOF;
```

The second problem was that my `or_expression` rule should be:

```
or_expression : and_expression (OR and_expression)*;
```

and not

```
or_expression : and_expression (OR or_expression)*;
```

The full corrected grammar is:

```
grammar filter;

tokens {
    TRUE = 'true';
    FALSE = 'false';
    AND = 'and';
    OR = 'or';
    LT = '<';
    GT = '>';
    EQ = '=';
    NEQ = '!=';
    PATHSEP = '/';
    LBRACK = '[';
    RBRACK = ']';
    LPAREN = '(';
    RPAREN = ')';
}

filter: expression EOF;

expression : or_expression;

or_expression : and_expression (OR and_expression)*;

and_expression : term (AND term)*;

term : atom (operator atom)? | LPAREN expression RPAREN;

atom : ID | INT | FLOAT | STRING | TRUE | FALSE;

operator : LT | GT | EQ | NEQ;

INT : '0'..'9'+;
FLOAT : ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')*;
STRING : '"' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|' ')* '"';
ID : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
```

And the resulting parse tree is:

[image: The correct parse tree]